# Add column and group by other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I get the sum of a column, grouped by another column? E.g for the following DataFrame

```
Paid    Week    
   5       1
   2       1
   7       2
   7       2
```

How would I get the following output?

```
Paid    Week
   7       1
  14       2
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to actually add the values. It also prints some other columns along with it.

```
print df.groupby(['Paid','Week']).sum()


Week Paid                                                     
1    0.0                                            
     0.5                                              
     2.4                                            
     3.0           
     3.8                                           
     3.9                                           
     6.6                                
2    0.0                                            
     0.9                                           
     2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.groupby('Week', as_index=False)['Paid'].sum()
```

Output:

```
   Week  Paid
0     1     7
1     2    14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.groupby(by=['Week']).sum()
```

Would give the following output:

```
    Paid
Week    
1   7
2   14
```

Use the below if you do not want to index the group labels.

```
df.groupby(by=['Week'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
    Week    Paid
0   1        7
1   2        14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['Week'])['Paid'].sum()
```